# F# web service data provider with local wsdl file

Tags: f#, type-providers

I am trying to write F# client for our web services. The example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/hh156503.aspx) looks very good except it uses the server url in the code.

```
type TerraService = WsdlService<"http://msrmaps.com/TerraService2.asmx?WSDL">
```

This prevents me from reading service url from configuration file at run time, and make deployment from dev server to production server difficult.

I am wondering if there is any WSDL provider that works similar to [Dbml Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/hh362328.aspx)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109959/f-type-provider-for-wsdl-and-basichttpbinding

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're looking for, but note that the URL provided as a static parameter is used to generate types, but if desired a different URL can be provided at runtime by using a different overload of the `Get...Soap` method.  This URL can come from wherever you want (e.g. you can read it from a config file if that's your scenario).  E.g.:

```
type TerraService = WsdlService<"http://msrmaps.com/TerraService2.asmx?WSDL">
let terraClient = TerraService.GetTerraServiceSoap(EndpointAddress(myRuntimeUrl))
```

Comment: Imagine you write code against development server and got everything working. And then you decide to deploy your code to work against production server, you will have to modify your source code to make it happen. This doesn't look like a good practice. I much prefer to modify config files for deployment.

Comment: @WeiMa - no, my point is that you don't need to modify your source code, assuming that all that's changing is the URL.  In my example code, `myRuntimeUrl` can be read from a config file without changing the source code of the application.

Comment: OK, I got what you meant. I think your suggestion will work. I still think that having something like WsdlService<"http://..."> in source code is less desirable than WsdlService<"myserver.wsdl">. Any way, thanks for helping.

Comment: This doesn't work when you need to switch between `http` and `https`.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing currently exists that does that but the code is open source so you could make a version of it that work's in the mode that you desire:[1](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/TypeProvidersImpl.fs#L536) [2](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/TypeProviders.fs#L966).