# F# WsdlTypeProvider MaxReceivedMessageSize

Tags: web-services, wcf, f#, f#-data

I am using F# and the WsdlTypeProvider with this code:

```
type svc = FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.WsdlService<"http://my.service.url?wsdl">
let svcClient = svc.GetServicePort()
```

It works quite well in most cases calling some method on the client. But in some cases I get this message:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Except there is no such property on the binding. The binding may be accessed using:

```
let binding = svcClient.DataContext.Endpoint.Binding
```

Casting the binding to BasicHttpBinding, which has the property, does not work either, because apparently the bindings are not related inheritance wise:

```
let binding = svcClient.DataContext.Endpoint.Binding :?> System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding
```

And it results in this error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding' to type
>   'System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding'.

So the question is: 
How can I increase the MaxReceivedMessageSize while using the WsdlTypeProvider?

There doesn't seem to be any settings in my App.Config, like there would be if I was attaching to a service in the regular way, by generating proxy etc.

Comment: Have you had a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109959/f-type-provider-for-wsdl-and-basichttpbinding

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing this code for testing purpose than it is ok to use BasicHttp binding but to support sessions and for security reasons you should not use BasicHttp for commercial use of application . Go for netTcp or WsHttp bindings. The following code works for netTcp binding.

```
<bindings>
 <customBinding>
 <binding name="CustomBinding_MyService">
      <binaryMessageEncoding>
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="200000000" maxArrayLength="200000000"/>
      </binaryMessageEncoding> 
      <tcpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="200000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000000" maxBufferSize="200000000">
        <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never"/>
      </tcpTransport>

    </binding>
</customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, since I am using the TypeProvider I don't see that I have much control over how the service will be connected. Also I don't have control of the service (it's out of my jurisdiction so to say). So I am not sure how I can use your answer.